# cannot view all data php

Tags: php, html

I have a code where I need to search for the specific data based on the type of outsource and the type of dependent (dropdown for both, 1 dropdown each). There is 3 type of outsource and 4 type of dependent. I get to do the searching when the outsource id is 1 and 2 along with the dependent. It is a must to choose the dependent when the user choose the outsource with id 1 or 2. When the outsource id is 3, there is no need to choose dependent since it is where the user will view all the data in the unless they want to view it with the dependent. But the problem is I cannot view the data when I choose that type of outsource. It come out as a blank page.

I don't know where did I do wrong with my code:

```html
<form action="prestasioutsource.php" method="post" name="vot">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#333333"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="txtTxt">
      <tr bgcolor="#BBFF77">
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" bgcolor="#0066CC"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>Laporan Prestasi Khidmat Luar</strong></font></td>
      </tr>
       <tr bgcolor="#BBFF77">
        <td width="34%" valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCDFF">Dari Tarikh</td>
        <td width="66%" align="LEFT" valign="top" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><input name="tarikh1" type="text" id="tarikh1" />
  <a href="#" onClick="displayDatePicker('tarikh1');"><img src="calender.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr bgcolor="#BBFF77">
        <td width="34%" valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCDFF">Hingga Tarikh</td>
        <td width="66%" align="LEFT" valign="top" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><input name="tarikh2" type="text" id="tarikh2" />
  <a href="#" onClick="displayDatePicker('tarikh2');"><img src="calender.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
       </tr>

      <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCDFF">Jenis Khidmat Luar</td>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><select name="jenis_outsource" class="txtBox" size="1">
        <option value="-">--Choose--</option>

        <option value="1"> Outsourcing</option>
        <option value="2"> Not outsource without charge</option>
        <option value="3">All</option>

        </select></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCDFF">Jenis Tanggungan</td>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><select name="jenis_tanggungan" class="txtBox" size="1">
        <option value="-">--Choose --</option>

        <?
        $result = mysql_query("select * from jenis_tangunggan");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$row->jenis?>"><?=$row->jenis?></option>
        <?
        }
        ?>

        </select></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top"><div align="center">
            <input type="button" name="add" value="Submit" class="cmdButton" onclick="popup('prestasioutsource.php')" />
                      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="cmdButton" />
        </div></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Above are the HTML code that I use and below is the next code where it redirect from the above code after being submit:

```js
class PDF extends FPDF
    {
        var $widths;
        var $aligns;

        function Header()
        {
        $this->SetLineWidth(0.4);
        $this->Line(12,30,287,30);
        //Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Helvetica','B',15);
        //Move to the right
        //Title
        if($_GET['tarikh1'] && $_GET['tarikh2'] && $_GET['jenis_outsource'] == 1 || $_GET['tarikh1'] && $_GET['tarikh2'] && $_GET['jenis_outsource'] == 2 )//from dropdown
        {
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM outsource ";
             $sql.= "WHERE  id = '$_GET[jenis_outsource]'";
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
            $row5 = mysql_fetch_object($query);
            $jenis = strtoupper($row5->desc);
            $this->Cell(250,10,'LAPORAN PRESTASI ' .strtoupper($row5->desc),'','','C');
            $this->Ln(6);
            $this->Cell(260,10,' DARI '. $_GET['tarikh1'] .' SEHINGGA '. $_GET['tarikh2'],'','','C');
            $this->Ln(6);

            }else if($_GET['tarikh1'] && $_GET['tarikh2'] && $_GET['jenis_tanggungan'] == 'PT' || $_GET['tarikh1'] && $_GET['tarikh2'] && $_GET['jenis_tanggungan'] == 'Inden' || $_GET['tarikh1'] && $_GET['tarikh2'] && $_GET['jenis_tanggungan'] == 'Interim' || $_GET['tarikh1'] && $_GET['tarikh2'] && $_GET['jenis_tanggungan'] == 'PT/Inden' )//from dropdown
        {
             $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM jenis_tangunggan ";
             $sql1.= "WHERE  jenis = '$_GET[jenis_tanggungan]'";
            $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
            $row6 = mysql_fetch_object($query1);
            $jenis1 = strtoupper($row6->desc);
            $this->Cell(250,10,'LAPORAN PRESTASI ' .strtoupper($row6->desc),'','','C');
            $this->Ln(6);
            $this->Cell(260,10,' DARI '. $_GET['tarikh1'] .' SEHINGGA '. $_GET['tarikh2'],'','','C');
            $this->Ln(6);

        }else {
            $this->Cell(250,10,'LAPORAN PRESTASI KESELURUHAN DARI '. $_GET['tarikh1'] .' SEHINGGA '. $_GET['tarikh2'],'','','C');
            $this->Ln(6);

        }
        //Line break
        $this->Ln(10);

        $this->SetFont('Helvetica','B',7);
        $this->SetWidths(array(10,50,20,30,30,30,30,20,30));
        $this->SetAligns(array('C','L','C','C','C','C','C','R','C'));
        $this->Row(array('Bil','Nama Penerima','Jenis Tanggungan','No Rujukan','Tarikh Bayaran','No Baucar','No Cek','Jumlah','Prestasi'));

        }
```

1st part of the code:

```js
if($_GET['tarikh1'] && $_GET['tarikh2'] && $_GET['jenis_outsource'] && $_GET['jenis_tanggungan'])
{
/*********************************************************/
    $tarikh = $tarikh[6].$tarikh[7].$tarikh[8].$tarikh[9]."-".$tarikh[3].$tarikh[4]."-".$tarikh[0].$tarikh[1];
    $jumlah = 0;
    $no = 0;
    $tarikh1 = $_GET[tarikh1];
    $tarikh2 = $_GET[tarikh2];
    $tarikh1 = $tarikh1[6].$tarikh1[7].$tarikh1[8].$tarikh1[9]."-".$tarikh1[3].$tarikh1[4]."-".$tarikh1[0].$tarikh1[1];
    $tarikh2 = $tarikh2[6].$tarikh2[7].$tarikh2[8].$tarikh2[9]."-".$tarikh2[3].$tarikh2[4]."-".$tarikh2[0].$tarikh2[1];

    $jenis_outsource = $_GET['jenis_outsource'] ;
    $jenis_tanggungan = $_GET['jenis_tanggungan'] ;

    if($_GET['jenis_outsource'] == 1 || $_GET['jenis_outsource'] == 2) {
    $query = " SELECT b.nama_syarikat,a.jenis_tangunggan,e.code_prestasi as prestasi,c.no_pesanan ,c.no_cek,c.tarikh_cek,c.no_baucar,sum(c.amaun) as amaun  FROM tangunggan a, transaksi_baucarlo c,penyelenggaraan_syarikat b,prestasi_syarikat e WHERE c.no_pesanan = CONCAT(a.no_tangunggan,'/',a.jb_code,'/',a.tahun) AND a.jenis_outsource = '".$jenis_outsource."' AND a.jenis_tangunggan = '$jenis_tanggungan' AND c.kod_syarikat=b.kod_syarikat AND e.id=c.prestasi and c.bank != '11' AND  c.status is NULL  AND c.tarikh_cek >= '$tarikh1' AND c.tarikh_cek <= '$tarikh2' GROUP BY c.no_pesanan,c.no_baucar ";

    $query .=" ORDER BY tarikh_cek,no_baucar ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $bil++;
    $row_data[] = array($bil,$row['nama_syarikat'],$row['jenis_tangunggan'],$row['no_pesanan'],SQLToDate($row['tarikh_cek']),$row['no_baucar'],$row['no_cek'],number_format($row['amaun'],2),$row['prestasi']);

    }

/*********************************************************/

    $pdf= new PDF();
    $pdf->Open();

    $pdf->SetTitle('CARIAN PRESTASI KHIDMAT LUAR');
    $pdf->SetMargins(23,35,15);
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();

    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',6);

    $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.2);

    $pdf->SetWidths(array(10,50,20,30,30,30,30,20,30));

    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',6);
    $pdf->SetAligns(array('C','L','C','C','C','C','C','R','C'));
    $pdf->MultiRow($row_data);

    $pdf->SetWidths(array(250));
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',6);
    $pdf->SetAligns(array(''));
    $pdf->Row(array(''));

    $pdf->SetWidths(array(220,30));
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',6);
    $pdf->SetAligns(array('R','C'));
    $pdf->Row(array('PRESTASI SYARIKAT','JUMLAH'));

    $pdf->SetWidths(array(220,30));
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',6);
    $pdf->SetAligns(array('R','C'));
    $pdf->Row(array('TIDAK MEMUASKAN',$total));
    $pdf->Row(array('KURANG BAIK',$total));
    $pdf->Row(array('SEDERHANA',$total));
    $pdf->Row(array('BAIK',$total));
    $pdf->Row(array('SANGAT BAIK',$total));

    $pdf->Output();
}
}

?>
```

2nd part of the code. I know it is a bit long code, but can somebody tell me whats wrong with it? I'm working on it since 2 days ago and I'll try everything. But the result still the same. And I'm sorry the code is somehow in malay in some part.

Comment: Why the Java tag? What does this have to do with Java? Some of the code looks like an entirely different language -- JavaScript.

Comment: Use Netbean or Eclipse IDE for PHP development. So you get the debug option.

Comment: post form method and GET arrays; I'd call that possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465645/php-how-to-fix-notice-undefined-variable

Comment: ...in other words, you're using `method="post"` and `$_GET`, those do not work together; not the way you're using them. Therefore, you need to use `method="get"` and error reporting would have thrown you a whole bunch of undefined index notices.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465645/php-how-to-fix-notice-undefined-variable

Comment: @Fred-ii- is right, the error is in the very first line of your code.

Comment: @Fred -ii- i'll try to change the method to get but it s still the same. i take a look at the post it doesn't look the same to as i don't get any error at all.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: i try that too, it give me the error that is not an error i guess since i have it in almost all of my code which is the date @Fred -ii-

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
  <form action="prestasioutsource.php" method="post" name="vot">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#333333"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="txtTxt">
      <tr bgcolor="#BBFF77">
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" bgcolor="#0066CC"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>Laporan Prestasi Khidmat Luar</strong></font></td>
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#BBFF77">
        <td width="34%" valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCDFF">Dari Tarikh</td>
        <td width="66%" align="LEFT" valign="top" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><input name="tarikh1" type="text" id="tarikh1" />
  <a href="#" onClick="displayDatePicker('tarikh1');"><img src="calender.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
       </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#BBFF77">
        <td width="34%" valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCDFF">Hingga Tarikh</td>
        <td width="66%" align="LEFT" valign="top" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><input name="tarikh2" type="text" id="tarikh2" />
  <a href="#" onClick="displayDatePicker('tarikh2');"><img src="calender.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
     
            
   <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCDFF">Jenis Khidmat Luar</td>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><select name="jenis_outsource" class="txtBox" size="1">
  <option value="-">--Choose--</option>
        
  <option value="1"> Outsourcing</option>
  <option value="2"> Not outsource without charge</option>
        <option value="3">All</option>
        
  </select></td>
      </tr>
   
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCDFF">Jenis Tanggungan</td>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><select name="jenis_tanggungan" class="txtBox" size="1">
  <option value="-">--Choose --</option>
        
  <?
  $result = mysql_query("select * from jenis_tangunggan");
  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
  {
  ?>
  <option value="<?=$row->jenis?>"><?=$row->jenis?></option>
  <?
  }
  ?>
        
  </select></td>
      </tr>
     
   <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top"><div align="center">
            <input type="button" name="add" value="Submit" class="cmdButton" onclick="popup('prestasioutsource.php')" />
                      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="cmdButton" />
        </div></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is nothing change even if i change my html code to those because it is already in those form, just i make it short by copy only those cut. XD